# Get rid of Google Now Cards nag from Google Search

Tags: google-now

It seems that Google recently updated Google Search on Android to set up "Now Cards".  I have no intention of enabling this.  I've disabled it in the Google Search settings, but it continues to nag me to set it up.  How do I disable it and get rid of this nag?

[image: screenshot of unwanted "get now cards"]

Comment: if you type any search term in home screen then you wont see any Now cards being displayed..but if u search in Google Now screen then you will see the suggestion first and then the cards(sports, weather etc) based on your configuration of Google Now

Comment: Lucky's comment has a point: why do you need to go to that screen if you want to perform a search? AFAIK, you can just search from any home screen with the Google Search Bar widget. **Or**, do you want to actually remove that part from the home screen (which I think is impossible unless using other launcher)?

Comment: I'm using a Samsung S5 and I prefer to access Google Search by pressing and holding the home button.

Comment: @Frotz If you dislike Now cards and you haven't configured then you wont see any Cards. so just igonre the Get Cards message..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Google has mooted this question by removing the nag.